# Is it preferred to import a class (ex. import flash.events.MouseEvent ) instead of the entire contents of a package (ex. import flash.events.*)

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there  benefit to specifying which class, function or namespace you intend to use at the beginning of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[the reference says](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#import):

> If you import a class but do not use it in your script, the class is
>   not exported as part of the SWF file. This means you can import large
>   packages without being concerned about the size of the SWF file; the
>   bytecode associated with a class is included in a SWF file only if
>   that class is actually used. One disadvantage of importing classes
>   that you do not need is that you increase the likelihood of name
>   collisions.

however, it's much more convinient (for me) to have an exact list of classes that are used in the code that follows

Answer (score 1):

It only affects compile time, and not to any great extent as far as I've noticed.

One benefit is that your import statements act as a "definition" of what external classes are used, but personally I don't really find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you call the specified object more than once in your code you have the benefit of saving keystrokes.  also, if the class is moved to a different folder it's much easier to simply update only one import line.  it's also cleaner looking, in my opinion.

i thought i tried writing the path once in my AS3 code and it wouldn't compile.  perhaps it was a setting i have but i was under the impression that this was not possible in AS3.